# python requests.get gets stuck

Tags: python, python-requests

I am making a python to read temperature from a simple server in a lan network each 2 seconds, the problem is that sometimes the script is stuck without doing anything, I'm using requests with python 3.6 on windows

```
import requests
import time

while True:
    s=time.time()

    r = requests.get("http://192.168.1.2/readtemp.php?id=1&action=read")
    temp = r.text
    print (temp + ' - ' + str(time.time()-s) + ' Seconds')
    time.sleep(2)
```

the response I get is this:

29°C - 0.272745847702026 Seconds

29°C - 0.64812617301941 Seconds

29°C - 0.294319868087769 Seconds

but sometimes when I come back to my computer I find it stuck doing nothing, any ideas why it gets stuck, isn't it supposed to keep making the request till it gets a response like browsers do?

Comment: Does the server still respond to browser requests? What are you using to run the server process? It should more like the server is getting stuck than the client.

Comment: use the `timeout` kwarg. then you can catch the `Timeout` exception - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Comment: @holdenweb yes it still respond to the browser request

Comment: @RobertSeaman I will give it a try, but it bothers me why would it timeout when it should work normally I'm using wamp server, I didn't encounter this issue with .net, is there somehow a way to know where did the function got stuck on python?

Comment: requests doesnt retry nor have a timeout by default, as using a timeout would inform you about a potential (and the most likely, my oppinion) issue. Either catch the exception and retry later or you can go the more advanced route of a retry adapter. http://www.coglib.com/~icordasc/blog/2014/12/retries-in-requests.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Tobias wrote, requests doesn't retry nor have a timeout by default, as using a timeout would inform you about a potential (and the most likely, my opinion) issue. Either catch the exception and retry later or you can go the more advanced route of a retry adapter.

Try this request with timeout & error handling:

```
import requests
import time

while True:
    s=time.time()

    try: 
        r = requests.get("http://192.168.1.2/readtemp.php?id=1&action=read", timeout=10)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as err: 
        print(err)
        # sleep some sec/min and retry here!

    temp = r.text
    print (temp + ' - ' + str(time.time()-s) + ' Seconds')

    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Explain why it will solve the issue at hand and also where the author went wrong

Comment: It is already explained in comments for the question, I copied it to the answer.

Comment: Many people who come here for help doesn't go through comments much. So it will be really helpful if you can add that up in your answer.